# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined caused by asinc calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsp, post

I am getting this error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I have doing some research and I have read that it could be an async issue.

Thats my code: json received call: accesWeb

The part of the JSON i need is the tActivitats

```
[
  {
      "identificador":"1AE2886120F41BBC0F76567993EF76E0",
      "article":null,
      "precioTemp":[
         {
            "codActiv":"1",
            "codTarifa":"1",
            "precio":"8.50",
            "dtePromo":"0",
            "dteEuro":"%",
            "total":25.5,
            "tipus":"normal"
         }
      ],
      "tActivitats":[
         {
            "mostrIdioma":"S",
            "calendariWeb":"S",
            "nomActiv":"Visita Museu",
            "codiActiv":"1",
            "tipus":"S",
            "idioma":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

That is my post call: There I want to store the tActivitats into a global array called result4. Then I call a function called loadSurvey where i pass that array.

```
 function fConstTabla(dataVisita){
        //other stuff
        $.post('../ActionServletJson', {
                elem : 'accesWeb',
                codiMuseu: gCodiMuseu,
                property: gProperty,
                dataVisita: dataVisita,
                lang: "<%=lang%>",
                sessionId: "<%=sessionActual%>"
        }, function(data) {
            if(data.length>0){
                if(soloArticulo)borrarCarritoArticulo(numGrupActiv)
                else{
                    $.each(data,function(t,elem){
                       // other stuff//

                        if(elem.article=="S"){//article
                            $.each(elem.articulos,function(tArtic,elemArtic){
                                // other stuff//

                            });
                        }else{//actividad normal o combinada


                            result4.push(elem.tActivitats);

                            //other stuff

                        }
                    });

                    //other stuff//

                    var mostrar="<%=lang(propLang, "formdades.mostrarEnquesta")%>";
                    if(mostrar.toUpperCase()=="T")loadSurvey("<%=sessionActual%>",result4);

                    var avisActiv='<%=lang(propLang, "carrito.avisActivitat")%>';
                    fConstObservActiv(a_codiActiv.join(','),avisActiv);
                    $( "button" ).button().click(function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            }else{
                //other stuff
            }
            hideLoading();
            mostrarPromocion(marcPromo);
        });

    }
```

Then I have the loadSurvey function (I have only copy until the line where I get the error)

```
function loadSurvey(sessionActual,result4){

    $.post('../ActionServletJson', {
                            elem : 'enquesta',
                            property: gProperty,
                            codiMuseu: gCodiMuseu,
                            lang: gLang,
                            sessionId: gSession,
                            date: new Date().getTime(),
                        }, function(data) {
        if(data.length>0 && data[0].totalPreguntes!="0"){

            //other stuff
            var count = 0;

            $.each(data,function(i,elem){


                if(auxNumGrupEnq!=elem.numGrup || auxNumElemEnq!=elem.numElem){//si hay varias linias, puede ser que alguna no tenga encuesta asignada
                    //other stuff

                    var nomactivitat =  fTrobarNom(result4[count],aActivitats,"","","activ");
                    count++
                    //other stuff
```

I get the error at doing result4[count] where it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Is this a async issue? How I can fixed it?

Comment: It's indeed async issue. You are trying to access data which is not set yet. Console log the result4 just above this error line, you will get the empty array.

Comment: but if i console log the result4 inside the method fConstTabla i wont get the empty array.

Comment: yes, i think it's an async issue... if you want to use result4 in the next call, you would have to return it from the first async call and chain your second call after your first.

Comment: That's because of asynchronous nature of javascript. You will have to call loadSurvey in fConstTabla function after the data on result4 is set. You can read how promise works or api call work in javascript to get better idea.

Comment: @ when the data in result4 is set? Like when the  $.post('../ActionServletJson', {
                elem : 'accesWeb', is done?

Comment: @Argee can you post an example?